# Set Videogular source in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, videogular

I'm try to set the video source statically in view for videogular in my ionic project.
I try with below code, but it seems not working. Anyway, I'm able to get it to work if I load source from the controller.

```
<vg-media vg-src="{'source':'http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4','type':'video/mp4'}"
  vg-tracks="config.tracks">
</vg-media>
```

Comment: You are using ionic v1 right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ionic v1. The thing is I want to display.